# mono db4o filenane unknown

Tags: c#, mono

Brand new to MOno/db4o and C#.

Simple db program and I get an outer stack error "Type Initialization Exception" and the inner stack error states the file name is unknown. I have the db4o.dll file in my references, I know it is something silly but I can't seem to locate an answer anywhere, thanks for the help, project is due on Monday!

```
using System; 
using Db4objects.Db4o;

public class Test {

    static string _file = "store.yap";

    public static void Main (string [] args){

        IObjectContainer db = Db4oFactory.OpenFile (_file);
        db.Close();
}
```

Comment: You probably need to create the file (using Db4o) before you try to open it... but I'm not actually experienced with db4o at all

Comment: db4o has a mechanism that creates the file if it doesn't exist. Maybe I have the wrong dll file? Or missing another file?